# Spring is using the same SessionFactory and ignoring configured transaction managers

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 2 different databases. I configure each one and then associated TransactionManager with the respective @Transactional services. The problem is that whenever I try to save it tries to use only one of the transaction managers. It completely ignores the other transaction manager. Here are the configurations: Also please note that these 2 saving operations run in 2 separate Spring integration asynchronous processes almost at the same time since the request is sent to the save(Product) and save(User) using a recipient-list.  Could this be the cause of the problem?

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @ComponentScan("com.edx.db2")
   @PropertySource(value=....)
   public class DB2Config {
   @Autowired
   private Environment env;



    @Bean 
    public UserDao UserDao(){
        UserDao UserDao=new UserService();
        return UserDao;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="db2SessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        return db2DBSessionfactory().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean db2DBSessionfactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = 
          new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(db2DataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.edx");
        sessionFactoryBean.
        setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialeCT...
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.d
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", e
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.passwor
        return properties;
    }


    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        try {
            DriverManage..
            return dataSource;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to create connection pool",e);
            return null;
        }

    }



    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="db2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm=new 
        HibernateTransactionManager(db2DBSessionfactory().getObject());
        htm.setDataSource(db2DataSource());
        return htm;
    }
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.edx.oracle")
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:...)
public class ORAConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ProductDao productDao(){
        return new ProductService();
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory oracleSessionFactory(){
        return oracleDBSessionfactory().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean oracleDBSessionfactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = 
            new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.edx.oracle");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="oracleTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm=new 
        HibernateTransactionManager
          (oracleDBSessionfactory().getObject());
        htm.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect"
        ,env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class",
        env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", 
        env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username",
        env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password",
        env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return properties;
    }



    @Bean
    public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
        try {
            DriverManagerDataSource dm=new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dm.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            dm.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
            dm.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
            dm.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            return dm;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Unable to create connection pool",e);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

}

```
  @Repository
  @Import(ORAConfig.class)
  @Transactional("oracleTransactionManager")
   public class UserService implements UserDao{

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory oracleSessionFactory;
  private Logger LOG=LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);
  private PayloadIndexExtractor payloadIndexExtractor;
  public UserService() {
  }

  public UserService() {
  }


  public void save(final UserInfo user) {
   try{
     //Changed from getCurrentSession()         
     Session session=oracleSessionFactory.openSession();
      session.save(user) ;


   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       LOG.error("Failed to save user",e);
   }
}
```

}

```
 @Repository
 @Import(DB2Config.class)
 @Transactional("db2TransactionManager")
 public class ProductService implements ProductDao {

 public ProducrService() {

 }
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory db2SessionFactory;



    public void saveProduct(Product) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(product);
    }
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my configuration? Please help

Comment: In the `ORAConfig` class, can you add `@Qualifier(value="oracleSessionFactory")` above `oracleSessionFactory()` method and try.

Comment: I tried did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a ChainedTransactionManager as the bean with name transactionManager. It has to contain both other HibernateTransactionManagers and will than take care that both are starting and committing a transaction with @Transactional

Code should look like

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager, PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager)
        throws Exception {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(oracleTransactionManager,
           db2TransactionManager);
}
```

Comment: The 2 transactions are being interleaved.  The reason is that both transactions are running concurrently in 2 separate asynchronous processes that are totally unrelated. So when save(Product) is running, save(User) is also running and joining the save(Product) transaction. Since they are 2 different databases and the same transaction manager is being used it fails.

Comment: I didn't mention it the answer, but you have to remove the values from the @Transactional annotation. There is no concept of joining a transaction so they have start at the same time.